# URL is indexed but description not available due to "this site's robots.txt"

Tags: seo, google-search, robots.txt

I have a similar URL indexed by Google

`https://example.com/companies/company?utm_source=xxx`

And this output:

`A description for this result is not available because of this site's robots.txt.`

Here is the robots.txt

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
Disallow: /static/*
Disallow: /templates/*
Disallow: /translations/*
Sitemap: https://example.com/sitemap.xml
```

I have two questions. Should this type of URL be indexed? If so, how can I remove that message about description?

Comment: This isn't your problem but you should remove the `*` from the end of all your `Disallow` rules.   Disallow rules are all "starts with" rules so the star isn't needed.   Only a few crawlers (such as Googlebot) understand the wildcards.   Other crawlers will be looking for things like "/static/*/foo" with a literal star in it.

Comment: "Should this type of URL be indexed?" - Isn't that a question we should be asking you?! Whoever created your `robots.txt` file seemed to think it should not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line

```
Disallow: /
```

And you're good to go.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Here * means all polite bot including Googlebot, BingBot, YandexBot will follow your robots.txt rules, and `/` meaning **all the directory is restricted to crawl.**

You should use only this rule.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /static/*
Disallow: /templates/*
Disallow: /translations/*
Sitemap: https://example.com/sitemap.xml
```

This robots.txt tell all polite bot to don't crawl all files inside static, templates and translations folder. So again if your sitemap contain these URL's

```
https://example.com/static/some-javscript.js
https://example.com/static/some-photos.png
https://example.com/templates/some/index.html
https://example.com/templates/translations/de/index.html
```

Then Google will still display that line in search results because you've block it for crawling, so understand robots.txt concept, it's not hard to understand at all.

Comment: thanks. If I understand correctly is good practice to index links from utm_source?

Comment: Yes it's totally fine, Google may soon automatically discover those parameters and will report you in your [search console property](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/crawl-url-parameters). UTM parameter is common and Google will handle it automatically.